# jquery load() causes a tags to lose their href value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="page">
    <a href="another-page.php">Click!</a>
</div>
<script>
$("a").click(function(){
  $(".page").load($(this).attr("href"));
  window.history.pushState("", "", '/'+$(this).attr("href"));
  return false;
});
</script>
<!-- in another-page.php -->
<a href="initial-page.php">Click here!</a>

<!-- what the another-page.php looks like once it's been loaded by jquery -->
<a href>Click here!</a>
```

and then clicking on a link will load a page in a `<div class="page">` BUT, I noticed at the top of the page, where there is a `<h1><a href="/">Title</a></h1>` it lost the color i had defined `h1 a {...}` and then when inspecting element, instead of being the above h1, a thing, it was `<h1><a href>Title</a></h1>`

Comment: pretty since nothings wrong with the code, probably check your loaded page if it's creating some conflicts with your main page. Your loaded page shouldn't include any other CSS styles or script files, to avoid issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Something else is wrong here.**

The issue I described occurs when you use `<a href=/>` not `<a href="/">`. I didn't test to check and see if the same occurs when using `<a href=another-page.php>` but found that, quoting the forward slash fixed the problem.